# Cannot install from CPAN (Perl)

Tags: perl, cpan

I am trying to install [perlcc module](http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/perl-5.8.9/utils/perlcc.PL#NAME) using cpan:

```
cpan[1]> install perlcc
Reading '/home/iuser/.local/share/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 08 Sep 2017 12:41:02 GMT
Warning: Cannot install perlcc, don't know what it is.
Try the command

    i /perlcc/

to find objects with matching identifiers.

cpan[2]> i /perlcc/
No objects found of any type for argument /perlcc/

cpan[3]>
```

Why is this module not getting installed even when search page is showing it to be there? How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Because this is no module but part of the perl-5.8.9 source tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`perlcc` is not a module. It is a command line executable.

Look at the page you link to:

[image]

… it is part of Perl itself.

Searching for *perlcc* using Google turned up [this page](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=654568) which says:

> perlcc has been removed from Perl effective Perl 5.10. It and the underlying modules have always been out of date, broken and unmaintained.

So you could install an old version of Perl ([perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/) might help there) to get access to it.

That page also says:

> Reini Urban has since fixed it and has been maintaining it as part of [B::C](http://search.cpan.org/~rurban/B-C-1.55/lib/B/C.pm)

So you could look at installing that instead.

Answer (score 2):

The `cpan` tool expects you to specify a *module name* or a *distribution name* in order to find the correct distribution. `perlcc` is not a module, but the name of an executable script.

To find the module name, search for the executable on https://metacpan.org. This brings us to the [`perlcc` documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/B-C/script/perlcc.PL). In the top left there is the distribution name (e.g. `B-C-1.55`). When we click on it we get a list of all modules in the distribution – any of them should work. In particular, `cpan> install B::C` should be able to find the correct distribution.

However, I wouldn't hold my breath for that tool. The test results are rather mixed, with no successful tests above perl v5.24.2 and very mixed results under previous versions. You might be more interested in R. Urban's controversial [cperl](https://github.com/perl11/cperl) fork of Perl.